# Detecting audio playing in a bash script

Tags: audio, ubuntu-11.10, bash-scripting

Is there a way to detect if any sound is playing (using a bash script)?

(I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 using pulseaudio.)

I plan on using it in an indicator to visually remind me sound is playing while the mute is on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using pulse-audio**: You can try `pactl list` to see what pulse audio is doing with the sound hardware. I'm leaving the specifics of pulling out the status to you. For e.g.: This command would list the `Sink` and `Source` states.

```
pactl list | grep State
```

**Using procfs for ALSA** (*Caveat: these proc entries might go away in the future*): This snippet runs through the pcm playback devices in ALSA proc heirarchy.

```
if grep -q RUNNING /proc/asound/card*/*p/*/status 2>&1; then
   echo "Playing"
else
   echo "Idle"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! `pactl list` is working for me. Volume, mute status, etc. How did you find this out? I've been searching for "pulseaudio status" and nothing this simple came up.

Comment: No problem :-) Find out the tools that come along with pulseaudio, then take a guess on the which one might be appropriate, check the man pages, try running it.

Comment: `pactl list` output is locale-dependent and will be shown according to `$LANG`.

Comment: `pactl` has a "short" format that's meant for parsing in scripts according to `man pactl`.  In my case, I can use `pactl list short sinks | cut --fields=5` to get the `RUNNING`/`IDLE` state directly.